# How to print sorted list column by column instead of row

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Trying to print an array of strings that are already sorted. So for example if I have a String array with letters A to L in order how do I set up a loop to get the output as such.  I cant seem to wrap my head around on how to increment the loop variable to get the correct number to print out the array in this order.

Desired Output:

```
   A D G J
   B E H K 
   C F I L


String[] str = { "A", "B","C" ,"D" ,"E" ,"F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K", "L" };
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will still need to print from left to right, top to bottom. There isn't a simple way to go back to a previous row and continue printing there.

You should be able to calculate the number of rows and columns in you table. Once you know those values, you can do the following:

1. Print out the the item at index `0` in your list.
2. Skip over a number of element equal to the number of rows you want (in your example this is 3).
3. Print out the next element (in this case `D`).
4. Repeat steps 1-3 until you get past the end of the array.
5. Print out a newline and repeat the above process except now you'll increase your starting index by 1 (for example, after the first iteration start at index `1`, start at `2` after the second iteration, etc.).
6. Once your starting index is greater than the number of rows, stop.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code to print in the required format. It does two loops - the outer loop prints the rows and the inner loop prints the columns for each row.

```
public class PrintArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"};
        printArray(str, 3);
    }

    private static void printArray(String[] str, int numRows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j += numRows) {
                System.out.print(str[j + i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A D G J 
B E H K 
C F I L
```